# How to redirect www.domain.com/.html to www.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm having problems with this kind of url

- www.domain.com/.html

I have a Google Search Console issue telling me that I have problems with that url. I want to make a 301 redirect to the root of the website

- From www.domain.com/.html to www.domain.com

Comment: The problem is not in subfolder, is in the root of the domain. I'll check it out but I tryed that solution before and didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was a 403 error (forbidden). Solved in httaccess with ErrorDocument 403 / redirection.